# Bearing vibration analysis from audio signal instead of velocimeter measurements

Tags: signal-analysis, audio

We currently test bearings on a third-party test machine, which uses a velocimeter and reports through a software front end that outputs a low mid and high band spectrum result, and RMS, Peak and Crest values. This machine also outputs the audio to a speaker, allowing us to listen for structure borne noise which may fall outside of the monitored bands. (We don’t know the internal workings of this machine, aside from basic theory).

We are attempting to develop our own solution in LabVIEW, that allows us to capture that outgoing audio signal, process it and replicate the results that the third-party machine gives us. Our approach so far has been to take the incoming audio signal, scale the signal using the ‘Scale Voltage to EU’ module, and then to pass the signal through a butterworth bandpass filter for 50-10k Hz, before calculating the RMS, Peak & Crest. We have exported the datapoints from the 3rd party machine into .csv and have done the same for the data points we have in LabVIEW, comparing the two datasets as shown below.

The bottom signal is from third-party .csv output and the top signal is from the LabVIEW .csv output.

Is what we're attempting to do even possible? Why do the patterns of the signals look so different?

[image]

Comment: You would need to add a lot more detail. From first looks: your LabVIEW signal is a strong sinusoidal component which could either be noise or an excitation that the 3rd party has removed. You don't show a time axis, so I can't eye-ball the frequency. I would suggest doing a spectral analysis on both signals.

Comment: @Hilmar Thank you for the advice, appreciated!